# multiple inbound database endpoint in 1 flow

Tags: mule

I am trying to create one flow where there could potentially be more than one database inbound end-point. The flow goes as follows:

1. Get rows from table X database A for rows with X.status (table X column status) = 'new'.
2. Get rows from table Y database B where Y.some_id = X.another_id. X is rows retrieved data from step(1).

   1. Insert new rows into table Z database B.

I realized that there could be one database inbound end-point. Is there any way I could accomplish this with Mule ?

Environment: Mule 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first DB call will be inbound and the second one will be outbound. Since the first DB call is reading from the database it will be inbound while the second one is receiving data which implies that it will be an outbound call.

step 1) Inbound database call - Read from database-A (table-X, column-status).

Step 2) The result (payload) will most likely be a list or a list of maps. You can query the individual fields using groovy script and setup a flow variable. for example

Because you have multiple rows coming in it is important to use the collection splitter to split every row of records.

To query status variable: #[flowVars['Var']['status']]. Similarly you can query for the remaining fields.

Now that you have your dataset ready from database A, write a query for your database B and use the flow variable (explained above) to query for Y.some_id. eg "where Y.some_id=#[flowVars['Var']['another_id']]"

Step 3) In the same outbound connection you can do the insert in database B (table-Z). What makes all this possible is because you are using specific database connectors.

A couple of advise:
1) Make database connectors and queries global (before the flow)
2) Use HTTP outbound endpoint so that you can control your flows run from a browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the accepted answer. In addition, I also used "Message Enricher" scope in the subsequent database outbound end-point

Answer (score 2):

You can declare multiple message sources in your flow by leveraging the `<composite-source />`scope.

Basically your flow would look like this:

```
<flow ... >
<composite-source>
<jdbc:inbound-endpoint ... />
<jdbc:inbound-endpoint ... />
</composite-source>
...
</flow>
```

[This documentation page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Application+Architecture) should provide you more informations on the topc